# Adding Media Attribute for Size Guide

Tags: magento-1.9

I wanted to be able to display a link on a product that will open up a new window showing a Size Guide if one is available. To do this I added a new **Media Image** attribute called **size_guide_media** and assigned it the type **Media Image** and added it to the product attribute group. It now shows as a column within the Images tab. Excellent. I can now assign an uploaded image as a size guide.

So I wrote this code into **view.php** to manage whether or not to show a link that opens up an assigned size guide:

```
<?php 
    // Check if size guide media attr has been set for product
    if ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSizeGuideMedia())) { 
    // Assign size guide img url to variable
    $size_guide_url = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'size_guide_media'); 
?>
<a href="<?php echo $size_guide_url; ?>" onclick="javascript:void window.open('<?php echo $size_guide_url; ?>','1435746173051','width=800,height=600,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=30,top=30');return false;" class="size-guide-button"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i><?php echo $this->__('Size Guide'); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

It works... almost. An issue arises when the following is done:

- I add a size guide to a product and set it to the size guide
  attribute
- Saved product now shows size guide link and works correctly.
- I now go back to the product editor, and set the Size Guide column under the images tab to **no media** and save the product.
- I Refresh the same product on the front end and the screen goes
  completely white.

I'm assuming this is down to my *if statement* and how it is checking to see if the variable size_guide_media is in use...

This bit:

```
  if ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSizeGuideMedia())) {
```

My question is what happens when a media image attribute is set to **no image**? Because this is when my code falls over...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the screen is going white, you should be able to set Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

Once that is set, you should start seeing some information as to what is causing the problem.  I suspect that the problem is as follows

1) Products who's size_guide_media have never been set do not have a value.  Therefore, never execute your code.
2) Once you set a value - your code will execute.
3) If you "clear" the value - it's trying to load a URL on an empty string or a string set to "".  This causes problems, and crashes the page.

I suspect if you add a 2nd check into your code thusly - things will work:

```
<?php 
// Check if size guide media attr has been set for product
if ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSizeGuideMedia())) { 
// Assign size guide img url to variable
**if ($_product->getSizeGuideMedia() <> "") {**
     $size_guide_url = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'size_guide_media'); 
**}**
```

Give that a try - and let us know.

Comment: I meant to come back to you on this but I forgot  - Okay so it nearly works but required another check to ensure the attribute isn't in "no_selection" mode after previously having been set with an image `if ($_product->getSizeGuideMedia() <> "" && $_product->getSizeGuideMedia() != "no_selection") { `